# CSS layout with wrappers and floating elements

Tags: html, css

I want have a wrapper within which I need a img on the left, button in the center, text in right, all in the same line. To center I tried

```
       {margin:0 auto;}
```

but it is not working. Also using separate  tag moves the elements with one line space.

CSS:

```
.wrapper
{
  width:70%;
  margin:0 auto; /* THIS IS WORKING FINE */
}

.custom_image
{
  float:left;
}
.custom_button
{
  background-color:#ff6600;
  border:2px; /* THIS IS NOT WORKING */
  border-color:#ccc; /* THIS IS NOT WORKING */
  padding:5px;
  margin:0 auto; /*THIS IS NOT WORKING */
}
.custom_text
{
  float:right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="custom_image"><img src="LOCATION"/></div>
  <div class="custom_button"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
  <div class="custom_text">TEXTS</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML and CSS styles?

Comment: may be float:left can solve your problem.

Comment: We can't help without your HTML/CSS - please post it and/or include a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I have added my CSS and HTML here.

Comment: Please see this.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260653/wrapper-layout-and-div-problems). This is again an issue many newbies like me will face. See if you could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You were pretty close, you just needed to take the button out of the inner `div` and center the text in the wrapper. Try it like this:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <div class="custom_image"><img src="http://www.petside.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/thumbnail_50x50/grumpy_cat_photo.jpg"/></div>
  <div class="custom_text">TEXTS</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    text-align:center;
    width:70%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.custom_image {
  float:left;
}
.custom_text {
  float:right;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zRpme/)

Comment: :Yes. :) I would love to know how a <div> is not inserting a new line ? Can you brief it please ?

Comment: Well, `.custom_image` and `custome_text` both have `float` assigned to them, so they are no longer displayed inline within the wrapper. By removing the `div` that contained the button, you no longer have any block elements that break line after them.

Comment: Please see this.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260653/wrapper-layout-and-div-problems) This is again an issue many newbies like me will face. See if you could help. Thanks.