# Wrapper layout and div problems

Tags: html, css

**Image**

[image]

I tried this with the following CSS and HTML. It looks fine when the browser is of full width and scrambled when browser is resized. I WANT the elements to be where there and a HORIZONTAL SCROLL has to appear when the BROWSER is RESIZED. Pretty new to web programming. Text-align:center for positioning the center column would not work because, every time a new text is added in the left or right, it gets relocated and also center column element in ROW1(text) and ROW2(Button) do not appear along the same line. That is, text appears a bit right and the button a bit left. Text-align won't work here.

CSS:

```
  @charset "utf-8";
  /* CSS Document */

  body
  {
       background-color:#000;
  }
  .wrapper
  {
      width:70%;
      margin:0 auto;
      padding:2px;
      background-color:#fff;
   }
   .second_row
   {
      padding:2px;
      margin-top:10px;
   }

   .center_container
   {
      width:30%;
      margin:0 auto;    
   }
   .left_container
   {
      width:33%;
      float:left;
   }
   .right_container
   {
      width:33%;
      float:right;
   }
   .topelements 
   {
      margin-top:0px;
      color:#777;
      padding:2px;
   }
   .topelements a:link
   {
      color:#29a3cc;
   }
   .topelements a:active a:hover
   {
      color:#29a3cc;    
   }
   .logo
   {

      overflow:hidden;
   }
```

HTML code:

```
  <div class="wrapper"> 
    <span class="topelements float_left" >Mail us: <a href="#">admin@admin.com</a></span>
    <span class="topelements float_right">Left links <a href="#">My xyz</a></span>
    <span class="topelements center_container">Welcome to xyz ! <a href="#">Sign in</a> or <a href="#">Signup</a>.</span>
   </div>
     <div class="wrapper second_row">
       <span class="left_container">Srini</span>
       <span class="right_container">Vas</span>
           <form class="center_container">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Goooooooooooo!" />
              <input type="submit" value="Search" />
           </form>
     </div>
     <div class="wrapper">
```

Comment: u need responsive layouts like "responsive grid" or "foundation"

Comment: Can you explain how to ? Send me a link for a tutorial please ?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/

Comment: @Shanimal: This is not what I want. If you can go to your facebook and resize the browser, a horizontal scroll bar appears below and the elements stay where they are and do not get scrambled. I need something like that. The elements must not get scrambled when resized but a scroll bar has to appear below to scroll through

Comment: so what you need is like a little frame for this content? it looks to me like overflow:scroll. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fwonf but this has nothing to do with columns. sorry... im confused. :) best of luck to you Srini Vas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align you object in the center, there are a couple of different ways. First of all, there is the `text-align:center;` which you don't need right now. There is also `object-position:center;` which basically does the same, but with an object. This way isn't the best, but you could add a certain percentage of `padding` to either side but that's not recommended. Lastly, there's `alignment-adjust:central;`. This may not be perfect for your situation but just try out all of these and see if they work. Good luck!

Comment: I got this. I need an absolute value for this to work. Relative positioning will never give me what I need here. Thanks !

Comment: The problem with absolute values is that it doesn't affect or get affected by any other elements especially with different screen sizes

Answer (score 1):

One way that would work is to set your wrapper width to a fixed value (something in 800px for example). As long as this width was longer than all the content you are putting within that wrapper, everything should work as you want. The browser will automatically place a horizontal scroll bar when the window gets smaller than the width of the wrapper.

Comment: Oh yes. It works fine. Have you got solutions for the other issues ?

Comment: Im not quite sure I understand your other issues. Please clarify

Comment: How do I center align the content without using text-align:center ? Instead you could also suggest me how to make a container in the center of the 'wrapper' div(width:960px;) to have my ROW1 text above Row2 button(please refer the image) ?

Comment: to center a div you can use the properties    margin-left: auto; and     margin-right:auto;

Comment: I exactly added that in my class "center_container" and it is not working.

Comment: I got this. I need an absolute value for this to work. Relative positioning will never give me what I need here. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is just a small error I found in the CSS and I don't know if this will help too much. The div you added was not referred to as a div, but a class. For example, if you wanted to style a div in CSS, you would do this:

```
#divname {
CSS for div goes here...
}
```

On the other hand, if you wanted to add a little style to a class, you would go like this:

```
.classname {
CSS for class goes here...
}
```

If you were wondering what the difference for each is, the answer is simple. A `class` can define multiple objects while the `divs` are just limited to one object or element.

Comment: I want a div with classes and I guess what I did was correct.

Comment: You can troubleshoot if you want by making some of the lines of code comments by doing this: /**/

Comment: How do I center align the content without using text-align:center ?